# How to convert a Bazaar repository to GIT repository?

Tags: version-control, git

We have a large bazaar repository and we want to convert it to a git repository. The bazaar repository contains the folders of each of the interns. Any documentation/code prepared by interns is committed in their directory so there are a huge number of commits.

What steps should be performed to securely convert the bazaar repository to a git repository so that we do not lose any commit information.

We firstly need to create a backup of the existing bazaar repository and then convert it.

Edit: I followed this link: http://librelist.com/browser//cville/2010/2/9/migrate-repository-bzr-to-git/

It's working fine on my system with Ubuntu. But when I try to run it on the actual server it gives me EOF error and crashes

```
Starting export of 1036 revisions ...
fatal: EOF in data (1825 bytes remaining)
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_11804
```

Edit 2: I also tried it on a new CentOS system and received the following error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng. It's a little old but worked fine for me to fork a launchpad project in github. Simply import all bzr branches and push on your remote git server. I recommend using bzr2.2, it was buggy when I tried with newer verion of bzr.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Which version of bzr and git-bzr-ng did you try it with?  What bugs did you encounter?

Comment: https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-bzr seems to be the version provided in distributions now.

Answer (score 1):

Currently [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) provides the integration via [git-remote-bzr](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git-remote-bzr) package, which lists as it's homepage https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-bzr.